# Guardando cambios en Fragments mediante una Interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Hace poco he llegado al mundo de la programación y estoy con un proyecto de `Android`. 
Tengo dos `Fragments` en una `Activity` en uno de ellos hay que estar escuchando si hay algun cambio en los datos que introduce el usuario , de ser así cuando pulso en boton Back o Salir debe aparecer un mensaje con

> "Hay cambios en el documento realmente quiere salir".

La implementación que hay ahora en el proyecto es mediante un `Interface`

```
public interface IDataFragment<E> {

     boolean hayCambios();

}
```

Este es uno de los `Fragments` que implenta la `Interface`

```
public class DatosExtra extends Fragment implements IDataFragment<Shipment>{
public boolean cambiosDetectados = false;
//más código
//si hay cambios en alguno de los campos, por ejemplo si se modifica un spinner
cambiosDetectados = true;


 @Override
    public boolean hayCambios() {
        return cambiosDetectados ;
    }


}
```

Y por último el Fragment que recoge los cambios hace

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{
private Fragment datosExtra ; 

         //muestro mensaje de cambios?
         if(haHabidoCambios())
          mostrarMensaje();
    //....
    //....
    private boolean haHabidoCambios() {
         return ((IDataFragment)datosExtra).hasChanged();
    }
        ....
}
```

Pero el caso que no siempre funciona, ya que en ocasiones al llamar a

> haHabidoCambios()

obtengo false , cuando debería estar en true y viceversa.

.Me pregunto si hay alguna forma de hacerlo más claro

Comment: Si el atributo `datosExtra` de `MainFragment` siempre será una instancia de `DatosExtra`, deberías hacer `private DatosExtra datosExtra;` y en `haHabidoCambios()` hacer simplemente `return datosExtra.hasChanged();`; si no es así tendrías que comprobar si es una subclase (`instanceof`) antes de hacer el `cast` a `IDataFragment`

Comment: Muchas gracias lo prueba ahora mismo

Comment: Cuidado que sólo es una sugerencia para mejorar el código, no una solución a la pregunta. Y de hecho, en la pregunta deberías específicar qué significa el "no funciona" (excepción, comportamiento inesperado - explicando qué esperas que pase y que pasa-, etc.)

Comment: gracias ya lo he modificado

Comment: Tengo un par de consultas: La funcion del segundo fragment es solo mostrar el mensaje? Y porque MainFragment tiene una instancia de otro Fragment adento?

Comment: Gracias!! No el segundo fragment hace otras muchas cosas, no solo enseñar un mensaje. Si ..bueno en realidad hay tres fragments dentro de un mismo fragment, no se decirte porque ya que es un código que he heredado¿ no es una buena práctica ?